# insert into database from Joomla form fields

Tags: database, forms, joomla, insert

I am beginner to Joomla! development and have created a very simple module.

How do I create a form with 3 text fields and then save the entered values into a database table?

Answer (score 14):

Try this example:

We will Post a user's first and last name to a table.

create a table in your database.  Note it should have the prefix "jos_"

We will call this form, "names".  So we will name our table "jos_names"

At the SQL line in PHPMyAdmin (or whatever tool you use..), do this query to create a new table:

```
CREATE TABLE `databasename`.`jos_names` (`id` int(11) NOT NULL auto_increment, `firstname` VARCHAR(100), `lastname` VARCHAR(100), PRIMARY KEY  (`id`) )
```

To simplify things, we will post the results to the same page..  Let's build the form:

```
<?php

/** post form to db module **/

// No direct access
defined( '_JEXEC' ) or die( 'Restricted access' );



//--POST YOUR FORM DATA HERE-->
$fname = $_POST['fname'];
$lname = $_POST['lname'];
//--END POST YOUR FORM DATA---|
//--build the form------------>
?>
<form name="names" id="names" action="<?php echo JURI::current(); ?>" method="post">
  <p><input type="text" name="fname" id="fname" value="" /></p>
  <p><input type="text" name="lname" id="lname" value="" /></p>
  <p><input id="submit" name="submit" type="submit" value="Submit Names" /></p>
</form>
//--END BUILD THE FORM--------|
<?
if( (isset($lname)) || (isset($fname)) ) {
   //first name or last name set, continue-->
   $data =new stdClass();
   $data->id = NULL;
   $data->firstname = $fname;
   $data->lastname = $lname;

   $db = JFactory::getDBO();
   $db->insertObject('#__names', $data, id);

}  else {
  echo '<h4>One Field Is Required!</h4>';
}

?>
```

That should do it.  If you are writing a traditional Joomla module, this should be your helper.php file.

NOTES:
Only include the "die" script once in a joomla document.. (defined( '_JEXEC' )..

JURI::current()  automatically reads the current page URL.  If you call echo JURI::current(); on a page with the url http://www.example.com/names, then it will display the same link.

It is important that the action="" points to the exact Url where you will publish this module.

Furthermore, it is considered bad practice to post data to 'SELF', but you are kindof limited with a module, so unless you build a component or a plugin, you should post your form to 'SELF' as done with this example. (JURI::current();)

When in the Joomla framework, it isn't necessary to declare your database name, username or password as Joomla is already "logged in"..  So instead of querying `databasename`.`jos__tablename`, in joomla you can replace the query with this: `#__tablename`.  In fact this is the best practice when dealing with db queries and Joomla because users do not have to use the default jos_ prefix, joomla automatically replaces "#*" with whatever the prefix.  In my case "#*" equals "jos"

Take note when querying the sql to create the table..  make sure you replace `databasename` with the actual name of your database..

That should do it.

If for some reason you are unable to post data:
1) Make sure the form doesn't redirect to a different page when you click submit.  If it does, change the form action""  to the absolute url to where this page is published.. then go from there.

2) Sometimes the $data =new method doesn't work.  This depends on how you set up your module, functions and classes.
Here is an alternative:

```
$db =& JFactory::getDBO();
$query = "INSERT INTO `#__names` (`fname`, `lname`)
    VALUES ($fname, $lname);";
$db->setQuery( $query );
$db->query();
```

Answer (score 0):

Try something like http://www.chronoengine.com/ - Chronoforms

Comment: nonsense! it's a programming question, that link is just a commercial component!

Comment: Whilst I agree that this is a programming question, the ultimate goal of what he wants to achieve can be done using that component (or indeed many others).

Answer (score 0):

You may run a custom query to get a result on tmpl file which is simple

```
<?php // no direct access
defined( '_JEXEC' ) or die( 'Restricted access' );
$category =  $_REQUEST['category'];
if(isset($category))
    {
$db = JFactory::getDbo();
$db->setQuery("SELECT machine_id FROM j25_machinefinder_products WHERE category = '$category'");
// Load the row.
$result = $db->loadRowList();

//your result will return here
print_r($result);



    }

 ?>
<form action="" method="get" name="usedequipment">
<select name="category">
<?php foreach($hello as $category)
    {
    ?><option value="<?php echo $category[0]; ?>"> <?php echo $category[0]; ?></option><?php
    } ?>

</select>
<input type="submit"  />
</form>
```