# how to insert many input field data by joomla module

Tags: php, mysql, database, joomla, module

am new to joomla module development. i want to create a data entry module, where will be some input field, that will insert data into my custom table. by help this link and Kevin answer [insert into database from Joomla form fields](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2842860/insert-into-database-from-joomla-form-fields)  i create 2 input field and success to store data into my custom table, but i need more input field like "email, phone, address, age..." ect, so wat will be this line?`if( (isset($lname)) || (isset($fname)) )`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do bare in mind that the answer that Kevin posted was 3 years ago and does not following Joomla coding standards.

To get data from input fields, you don't use `$_POST`. you need to use `JInput`

```
$input = new JInput;
$post = $input->getArray($_POST);
$lname = $post["lname"];
$fname = $post["fname"];
// add more here
```

To insert data into your database table, use Joomla coding standards like so:

```
$db = JFactory::getDbo();
$query = $db->getQuery(true);

$columns = array('lname', 'fname'); // add more table columns here
$values = array($db->quote($lname), $db->quote($fname)); // add more values here

$query
    ->insert($db->quoteName('#_table_name'))
    ->columns($db->quoteName($columns))
    ->values(implode(',', $values));

$db->setQuery($query);

$db->query(); // Use for Joomla 2.5
$db->execute(); // Use for Joomla 3.x
```

I've added comments where you can add more data. Please note the last 2 lines of the code. Only use 1 of the lines depending on which version of Joomla you're using

Hope this helps

Comment: Thanks Lodder. heartly tnx to you. i did it. sir hope you will stay with me, coz i have many question and hope you will teach me like this answer. Thank you again